# lables output in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading about multiindex/advance indexing at following location

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html

```
In [1]: arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
   ...:           ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
   ...: 

In [2]: tuples = list(zip(*arrays))

In [3]: tuples
Out[3]: 
[('bar', 'one'),
 ('bar', 'two'),
 ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'),
 ('foo', 'one'),
 ('foo', 'two'),
 ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two')]

In [4]: index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])

In [5]: index
Out[5]: 
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

My question is how to interprets labels output? And how this output is produced from given input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Levels are all possible unique values of `MultiIndex`. 
`labels` map this levels.

So for first level `['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux']` is mapped by positions defined in labels `[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]` and output is `['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']`. It works same way for all levels.

If check [defined levels](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#defined-levels) is possible some levels are not used, but all possiblevalues are present in `levels`.

So:

```
print (index[:4].values)
[('bar', 'one') ('bar', 'two') ('baz', 'one') ('baz', 'two')]

print (index[:4])
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

For remove it is possible use [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html), *New in version 0.20.0*:

```
print (index[:4].remove_unused_levels())
MultiIndex(levels=[['bar', 'baz'], ['one', 'two']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]],
           names=['first', 'second'])
```

Answer (score 2):

`labels` is a list of lists in which each sub-list must be the same length.  That's because the length of each sub-list is the same as the length of the index itself.  Each member of each sub-list is the position of the corresponding `levels` sub-list.

So the first element of this `pd.MultiIndex` will be determined by the first elements of each `labels` sub-list.

The first element of the first sub-list is `0` and that corresponds to `'bar'`.  The first element of the second sub-list is `0` and that corresponds to `'one'`.  Meaning the first element of the index is `('bar', 'one')`

This becomes more apparent when we see that we can slice the `levels` sub-list with the `labels` sub-list.

```
index.levels[0][index.labels[0]]

Index(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='first')
```

And

```
index.levels[1][index.labels[1]]

Index(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'], dtype='object', name='second')
```

And we can zip them together to create what we would expect

```
list(zip(index.levels[0][index.labels[0]], index.levels[1][index.labels[1]]))

[('bar', 'one'),
 ('bar', 'two'),
 ('baz', 'one'),
 ('baz', 'two'),
 ('foo', 'one'),
 ('foo', 'two'),
 ('qux', 'one'),
 ('qux', 'two')]
```